# How to hide parent <li> if all the children are hidden in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new in Jquery

My Webpage structure is like this

```
 <div id="MenuSection">
    <ul>
       <li>Master                 // Main Menu
           <ul>
               <li>Master1</li>
               <li>Master2</li>
               <li>Master3</li>
           </ul>
       </li>
       <li>Transaction            // Main Menu
           <ul>
               <li>Transaction1</li>
               <li>Transaction2</li>
               <li>Transaction3</li>
           </ul>
       </li>
       <li>Report                 // Main Menu
          <ul>
              <li>Report1</li>
              <li>Report2</li>
              <li>Report3</li>
          </ul>
       </li>
   </ul>
   </div>
```

I want that when all the children of any Parent(main menu) are hidden, Parent should also be hidden. Let's say if Report1, Report2, Report3 are hidden then Parent that is "Report" should also be hidden.

How can I achieve this through Jquery ?

Comment: Do the opposite one. Hide parent ,all the children will be hidden.

Comment: @Tuhin it depends on *how* the children are being hidden.

Comment: A jq selector could be: ['li:has(li):not(:has(li:visible))'](https://jsfiddle.net/n81ovb6o/) but better is to use `$.fn.filter()` imho

Comment: May it help! [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/Lq0gvxfa/#&togetherjs=Kdl8NMvPpn)

Answer (score 2):

One way is to iterate over each main menu `li` to see if its children are all [:visible](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/):

```
$("#MenuSection>ul>li").each(function() {
  if ($(this).find(">ul>li:visible").length == 0) {
    $(this).hide();
  }
});
```

there are other ways to do this, such as using .filter or .map, but this should get you what you need.

Given the nested `ul`'s the above uses `>` to ensure only the directly `ul>li` children are processed.  If you have multiple levels, you might need to change accordingly, eg for the first: `#MenuSection li` would apply to all `li`s and the second `.find(">ul>li:visible")` only looks at direct `li` children.

```js
$("#MenuSection>ul>li").each(function() {
  if ($(this).find("li:visible").length == 0) {
    $(this).hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="MenuSection">
  <ul>
    <li>Master
      <ul>
        <li>Master1</li>
        <li>Master2</li>
        <li>Master3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Transaction
      <ul>
        <li>Transaction1</li>
        <li>Transaction2</li>
        <li>Transaction3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Report
      <ul>
        <li style='display:none'>Report1</li>
        <li style='display:none'>Report2</li>
        <li style='display:none'>Report3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @freedomn-m   Your code is working fine but when there is not child for any parent. Actually I am hiding the selected children on page load. After that I want to hide parent when all the children are hidden.

Comment: You should be able to call the code above *after* your code to hide the children.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does it fairly easy. You would need expand on this to execute this check every on the relevant list every time you hide or show a list item.

```
function isHidden(array) {
  for(var i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
    if(array[i+1].style.display != "none") {
        return false;
    };
  };
  return true;
};

var children = document.getElementById("report").getElementsByTagName("LI");
if (isHidden(children)) {
  document.getElementById("report").style.display = "none";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the the [.is(':visible')](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

See the code:

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var $mainLinks = $('#MenuSection > ul > li');

    $.each($mainLinks, function() {
      if (!$(this).find('li').is(':visible')) {
        $(this).hide();
      }
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
#MenuSection > ul > li:last-child li {
  display: none;
}
#MenuSection > ul > li:first-child li:first-child {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="MenuSection">
  <ul>
    <li>Master // Main Menu
      <ul>
        <li>Master1</li>
        <li>Master2</li>
        <li>Master3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Transaction // Main Menu
      <ul>
        <li>Transaction1</li>
        <li>Transaction2</li>
        <li>Transaction3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Report // Main Menu
      <ul>
        <li>Report1</li>
        <li>Report2</li>
        <li>Report3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```